# Length of cross product vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vectors $u$, and $v$, I know that $\mid u \mid$ = 3 and $\mid v \mid$ = 5, and that $u\cdot v = -12$. I need to calculate the length of the vector $(3u+2v) \times (3v-u)$.

Because I know the dot product of the vectors I know what cosine of the angle between them is $\cos \theta = -0.8$, and also $\sin \theta = 0.6$ Using this I started calculating the components of the vectors, but got nowhere. Am I missing some sort of fast, clever way of doing this?

Comment: Can you show that $(3u+2v)\times(3v-u)=11u\times v$?

Comment: I managed to work it out, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** $u\times u=v\times v=0$

**Hint 2:** $|u\times v|^2=|u|^2|v|^2-(u\cdot v)^2$

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of the cross product of $u$ and $v$ is equal to the area of the parallelogram determined by $u$ and $v$, 
$$\|u \times v\| = \|u\| \cdot \|v\| \cdot \sin \theta$$